# Calculate closed loop gain of an op-amp using "pspice"

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice

How do we calculate the closed loop gain of an op-amp **using Pspice**? Using DC/ AC simulation?

[image]

We know that the closed loop gain of this amplifier is -Rf/ Ri.

Comment: ...or V(out)/V(in).

Comment: For additional pointers, you can visit [this](https://resources.ema-eda.com/ema-blog/quick-tutorial-graphing-the-open-loop-gain-of-a-circuit-in-pspice) link.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to simulate the output as shown, then change V3 to -2V and simulate again.

The gain is \$\Delta V_{OUT}/\Delta V_{IN}\$

That eliminates the effect of offset voltage.

Comment: I see, thank you. Based from your answer, I applied the bias point analysis to find the Vout then applied dc sweep and added trace; specifically V[Rf] & V[Ri], using the Analog Operators and functions on the right side of the trace window, I solved the gain located at the 0-intectept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DC gain, do a [DC transfer function analysis](https://spiceman.net/ltspice-dc-transfer-analysis/) `.tf`
If you want AC gain do [an AC analysis](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-ac-analysis-using-the-step-command.html) (`.ac`)